# How can I perform the equivalent of shellexecute() in Lazarus for a Mac?

Tags: delphi, macos, pascal, lazarus

How can I perform the equivalent of `shellexecute()` in Lazarus for a Mac?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

{ Here is code to do it.  Use the TProcess object! }

```
uses Process;

...

procedure DoProcess;
Var
  Proc : TProcess;

Begin
  Proc := TProcess.Create(nil);
  try
    Proc.CommandLine := '/Applications/MyApp.app';

    PRoc.Options := Proc.Options + [poWaitOnExit];
    Proc.CommandLine := Proc.CommandLine + ' -someparam';
    PRoc.Execute;
  finally
    Proc.free;
  end;  
End;
```

Answer (score 3):

I don't know whether Lazarus libraries do already have this functionality wrapped, but if not you could write a conditionally compiled version of *ShellExecute()* using the info in the [Launch Services Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/LaunchServicesConcepts/LSCIntro/chapter_1_section_1.html).

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use ShellExecute to open a document with its preferred application, then you can use the OpenDocument procedure from the LCLIntf unit.

The Lazarus conversion tool also uses this replacement for ShellExecute, see the [Lazarus wiki](http://wiki.lazarus.freepascal.org/Delphi_Converter_in_Lazarus#Function_call_replacement). Internally it uses open as mentioned by RobS.

Answer (score 0):

I've successfully used `Shell('open ' + Filename)` in OS X 10.4 and 10.3 which seems to work rather nicely for most filetypes.

I stumbled across `open` at the shell prompt and now miss it in cygwin/linux etc.

Answer (score 0):

fork hurts on Mac. BSDs use vfork, not fork.